# Call c# xamarin function from Angular 2 typescript on click event

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was trying to call c# Xamarin function from Angular2 web application which is rendered in the webview of the c# xamarin.

I tried to call Xamarin function from plain html and javascript and I am able to call the function . This works fine for plain html and javascript.

```
onclick="MyClass.customInvoke('18475555555')"
```

But when i try to achieve this in Angular2 web application using

```
(click)="MyClass.customInvoke('18475555555');"
```

This is the error which i am getting

11-18 10:50:55.994 I/chromium( 9185): [INFO:CONSOLE(23925)] "[object Object]", source: https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.dev.js (23925)
11-18 10:50:56.004 I/chromium( 9185): [INFO:CONSOLE(324)] "Uncaught EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"
11-18 10:50:56.004 I/chromium( 9185): ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot call method 'customInvoke' of undefined
11-18 10:50:56.004 I/chromium( 9185): ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:

Comment: What's the relation between `MyClass` and `customInvoke`?

Comment: @echonax MyClass is an xamarinAndroid interface class  and customInvoke is a method in xamarinAndroid. I am trying to render the Angular2 webapplication in xamarinAndroid Webview and calling the xamarinAndroid function.

Comment: I would try to create a wrapper. (click)="callMyInvoke()" and inside global callMyInvoke I would call MyClass.customInvoke('18475555555')

Comment: @YuriS The wrapper idea worked. Thanks.

Comment: Arv im also doing same kind of task so can i know how you set the webView in mainActivity. Have you used LoadUrl because as its a angular routing is also hadle inside can you direct mr in to right path